# dynamic excel sheet names with sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, worksheet

I want to pass the dynamic excel sheet name as a variable. The name of the sheet can be either Table 1 or Table 1-1. Here is the code I have so far. In this code the name of the table is Table 1-1. I have been searching for a few days to try to find hints but to no avail.  It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
    SELECT [table 1-1] [hi],F3 [First Name] ,F4 [Last Name], F5 [Sex],F6 [Birth Date],F7 [dbf],F8 [asf],F9 [pabf] 
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',

   'Data Source=D:\name\Files for\T1515338;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...['Table 1-1$']

   where (F9 is not null AND F9 NOt LIKE '%Previously%')
```

Comment: Where does the table name come from?  How did you know that for this query it would be 'Table 1-1'?

Comment: I know for sure it would one of the two table names because I get the excel files every 3 months and I have analyzed the previous excel files.

Comment: Are you asking how to write the query so that you can pass a variable sheet name?

Comment: Yes just for passing the variable sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on this but maybe you could use @local_variable.
You first of all have to DECLARE a local variable to use then assign your value to it.
See [this link as a possible starter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx)